# Add grob to a base plot in R

Tags: r, plot, viewport, grob

I would like to add a multiline text that I have constructed using `splitTextGorb` from the package `RGraphics` to a base plot. I tried the following but this doesn't work (i.e the text doesn't show on the plot)

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE), heights = c(1,1.5))    
plot(...)
grob = splitTextGrob("This is my text")
plot.new()
vp.BottomRight <- viewport(height=unit(.5, "npc"), width=unit(0.5, "npc"), 
                       just=c("left","top"), 
                       y=0.5, x=0.5)
print(grob, vp = vp.BottonRight)
```

I know that `mtext` is an option to add text to a base plot, but I would like to use `splitTextGrob` specifically because it offers some flexibility that `mtext` or `grid.text()` doesn't.

Comment: I think you've got a solution, so please choose an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This uses gridBase package to add the text to the current viewport of the plot.

```
library(RGraphics)
library(gridExtra)
library(gridBase)


layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE))

# First base plot
plot(1:10)

# Grid regions of base plot
vps <- baseViewports()
pushViewport(vps$inner, vps$figure, vps$plot)

# Text grob
grob <-  splitTextGrob("This is my text")
vp.BottomRight <- viewport(height=unit(.1, "npc"), width=unit(0.1, "npc"), 
                       just=c("left","top"), 
                       y=0.2, x=0.8 )
# Add text grob
pushViewport(vp.BottomRight)
grid.draw(grob)

upViewport(4) 


# Second plot
plot(1:10)
vps <- baseViewports()
pushViewport(vps$inner, vps$figure, vps$plot)
pushViewport(vp.BottomRight)
grid.draw(grob)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `grid.draw()` for grob and gTree objects.

`grid.text()` is only for text and plotmath expressions.